# magento order show due payment even full payment is done

Tags: magento

In magento site customer has placed order and via card  submitted full payment but magento showing some amount as due payment. Actually my customer paid $1536 but order status show $1518 as paid and $18 as due.

I ask to customer and he said that $1536(full amount) is deducted from his account.
Please help me what may be issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please mention payment method used.

Comment: Hello Muk, i am using "Moneris Payments Checkout With Redirect" payment method.

Comment: As it is a paid extension contact the extension provider and to reproduce the issue try to place the sample order similar to one that your customer placed on the site.

Comment: Yes, Muk i already sent request to support but he is not responding me that is why i post issue here.                                                                         Ok, i wait for support response and thanks to you :)